# How do you execute a makefile to recompile django oscar assets?

Tags: python, django, makefile, compilation

I have a django oscar platform that I have amended.
The amendments haven't been implemented yet and I think this is because assets need to be recompiled.

I think to recompile the platform I need to execute this [makefile](https://github.com/edx/ecommerce/blob/master/Makefile)

How do I do this?

Comment: Have a look at lines 6 to 32.

Answer (score 0):

1. sudo -H -u ecommerce bash
2. source /edx/app/ecommerce/ecommerce_env
3. cd /edx/app/ecommerce/ecommerce/
4. make requirements
5. make static